# Adobe livecycle display multiple data in the livecycle table

Tags: livecycle, livecycle-designer, lcds

I am new to Adobe livecycle workbench. I am creating dynamic pdf forms for output purpose only. I have created a form using livecycle designer and able to bind the data using OLEDB database connection, but I am not able to fetch the multiple data from the database using OLEDB connection because it returns only single object to bind.

I am a java developer and have the idea about WSDL file and XML Schema. Can anybody help me to bind the multiple data from the database in livecycle forms using WSDL or XML schema? Suppose if we have a table in livecycle then how I will bind the multiple rows/records of the table into the multiple records of the database?

Please add any reference link to resolve this issues.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set the subform to repeat. Inside LiveCycle Designer:

`Object->Binding->Repeat Subform for Each Data Item [x]`